# How to draw on android canvas without losing previously drawn object?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

In android, is it possible to draw something on canvas, Then draw something else to the same canvas without losing the previously drawn objects?

**Details**:

- Display a drawable (based on image url).
- Upon clicking a node, display 5 more nodes (which drawables to display is determined by a remote api call).
- Now clicking on any of the 5 nodes will follow same steps to display 5 more nodes & so on.

I have gotten to a point where the first drawable is clicked & 5 more drawables are fetched. But when I translate the canvas & render the 5 nodes (invoking OnDraw), the first drawable is gone (expected). I dont want to draw all nodes again.

**1) So how to append to the same canvas?**

**2) Is canvas.concat the way to go? If so any pointers on how it could be used?**

My OnDraw method:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    canvas.translate(50,50);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

**UPDATE1**:
I found that this can be achieved only with a workaround. Basically, I need to create a bitmap/Canvas outside onDraw, draw my drawables on this new canvas & then, when done,  draw this pre-drawn bitmap on the canvas supplied by onDraw. But the problem with this approach is that when I create a bitmap, I need to provide a dimension. But the nodes can grow in size & there is no guarantee that I can accommodate them grown-nodes within 1000x1000. Assigning bigger numbers can result in out of memory. So unless there is a way to make the bitmap dimension match the canvas (impractical right?) I need to change my approach (SurfaceView?) here... suggestions welcome.

```
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
```

Comment: reuse the same bitmap ur drawing on, if i understand your problem correctly ..

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Elmorabea. I only create new bitmap only when it is null. So I am reusing. The problem is the size of the created bitmap as explained in my update.

Answer (score -1):

Did you call "canvas.drawColor(*your_background_color*)" **before** you call onDraw(Canvas canvas) function? If you do that just remove that line, which will clean your canvas as the color you assigned.

Comment: No I don't use canvas.drawColor before onDraw. I updated the question with things I did.